# C# asp.net MVC: When to update LastActivityDate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and creating a public website. I need to keep track of users that are online. I see that the standard way in asp.net of doing this is to keep track of `LastActivityDate`. My question is when should I update this?

If I update it every time the users clicks somewhere, I will feel a performance draw back. However if I do not do that, people that only surf around will be listed as offline.

What is the best way to do this in asp.net MVC?

Comment: Does anyone know how facebook does this?

Comment: I assume facebook is constantly making checking this in one of its many ajax calls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put an ajax javascript call at the bottom of your master page to track this.

Don't worry about performance at this time.  If it's implemented and you see it being a problem then come back to finding a better solution.  Something so simple shouldn't be a performance problem.

Just think about it like Google analytics.  It sits at the bottom of millions of pages with little to no impact on the user experiences of those sites.

Comment: Great tip. Ended up doing this :)

Comment: @user594166: I put the code inside `$(document).ready`... See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12720372/114029.

Answer (score 6):

Just ran into the same problem, here's my answer for MVC users:

The idea is to trigger Membership.GetUser("..", true) for every page load. This will automatically update the LastActivityDate.

I put this in my global.asax under "RegisterGlobalFilters":

```
filters.Add(new MembershipTriggerLastActivityDate());
```

I created a new class that looks like this:

```
class MembershipTriggerLastActivityDate : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, true);
        }   
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I started using the [SimpleMembershipProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12702649/114029). It's so simple that there's no more `LastActivityDate` tracking. So I had to roll my own.

I just added a `LastActivityDate` column in the Users table and was good to go...

Following [@Jab's tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2710051/114029) and using the `_Layout.cshtml` page (master page) in an ASP.NET MVC app, I did this with the help of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready((function () {

    var isUserAuthenticated = '@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated';

    if (isUserAuthenticated) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action(MVC.Account.ActionNames.UpdateLastActivityDate, MVC.Account.Name)",
            data: { userName: '@User.Identity.Name' },
            cache: false
        });
    }
});
```

Here's the action method:

```
public virtual ActionResult UpdateLastActivityDate(string userName)
{
    User user = Database.Users.Single(u => u.UserName == userName);

    user.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now;

    Database.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

    Database.SaveChanges();

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Only 133ms (YMMV) :-)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why not implement the update to LastActivityDate as an asynchronous call?  That way you can fire the update and continue processing.

Comment: Is there any event in the global.asax that will catch these async perhaps?

Comment: Application_BeginRequest gets called in the global.asax.  You could theoretically use that entry point to log the date for the user.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jab says, just implement it and if you see it as a performance issue in the future - deal with it then.

This is how I've done it in my application:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    if ((Response.ContentType == "text/html") && (Request.IsAuthenticated))
    {
        var webUser = Context.User as WebUser;
        if (webUser != null)
        {
            //Update their last activity
            webUser.LastActivity = DateTime.UtcNow;

            //Update their page hit counter
            webUser.ActivityCounter += 1;

            //Save them
            var webUserRepo = Kernel.Get<IWebUserRepository>(); //Ninject
            webUserRepo.Update(webUser);
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't had any problems with performance.

HTHs,
Charles

Answer (score 2):

I put it into a special queue that allows only one of a given key to be in the queue (and use the userId as the key in this case).  Then I have a low priority thread that works its way through this queue doing database updates.  Thus no slow down for the user, and one user doing 100 updates in one second doesn't cause any harm.  If it ever becomes an issue I'll make those updates into batch updates against the database but for now this approach works just fine.

If the application crashed I'd lose a few seconds of last activity data but that's just fine. Of course I also update the in memory User object every time so that it's reflected in the UI even if it hasn't made its way to the database yet.  Typically it's there before they've received the completed page anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using InProc SessionState, use the [SessionStateModule.End](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end) event. This happens when the session state is evicted from the underlying cache storage. Typically this happens after 20 minutes of inactivity, you can set the time in web.config.

Comment: This event does not seem to fire properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, have thought about that too and how accurate these mechanisms can be considering performance, a couple of ideas:

1) Track the the last login date

2) Use the LastLoginDate + the expected session length to set some kind of LastOnlineDate that can be used to check if the user is online.

Comment: But what happens if a user signs in and then surfs arround for 3 hours and the session length is 20 mins? Then the user will be listed as offline incorrectly. Which would happen in most cases?

Comment: You could store this LastOnlineDate in session and set some flag to update this based on a user action (page load)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is big penalty in performance if you fetch the current logged-in user on every request and update the `LastActivityDate` field every time (if you have care and invoke the `GetUser` method for the logged-in user once per http-request). In this way you can also make sure you always have the user's data fresh, like email, name, etc in case he/she updates that data.

Comment: Would holding this LastActivityDate in a separate table that only includes the UserID|LastActivityDate reduce some overhead?

Comment: @Mark - that would surely just add an unnecessary JOIN

Answer (score 0):

I tried **Charlino**'s code in the Global.asax like this

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Response.ContentType == "text/html") && (Request.IsAuthenticated))
        {

        }
    }
```

However I was getting the `Request.IsAuthenticated` false all the time.
So I moved the code to a method in my `Site.Master page`like this

```
 public void RegisterActivity()
    {
        if ((Response.ContentType == "text/html") && (Request.IsAuthenticated))
        {
            string userName = Page.User.Identity.Name;

            UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
            AppUser appUser = userManager.FindByName(userName);
            appUser.LastActivityDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            userManager.Update(appUser);
        }
    }
```

I call the method from the `Master page` `Page_Load` event, and there it worked.

I'm using `asp.net Identity` not `Membership` but I added an `AppUser` class inheriting from the `IdentityUser` class and in the `AppUser` class I added `LastActivityDate property`.

This is in a `WebForms Applicaction` not `MVC`.