# Set MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts in SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, security, webmatrix

I want to use [`SimpleMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider(v=vs.111).aspx) for membership management. and use [`MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.maxinvalidpasswordattempts(v=vs.111).aspx) SO when user tries to login and if [`MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.maxinvalidpasswordattempts(v=vs.111).aspx)exceeds. It should deactivate the account.  I want to Set [`MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.maxinvalidpasswordattempts(v=vs.111).aspx)  in [`SimpleMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider(v=vs.111).aspx) But its not happening.

**EDIT :**
Okay, I learned that its not possible. So, I have to inherit the [`SimpleMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider(v=vs.111).aspx) class and override those functions.

**REQUEST :**
Can anybody give the already implemented class with all the functions in it, just like the `SqlMembershipProvider`.

Comment: what is the question plz ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. At least not in code, because it's a [read-only property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.maxinvalidpasswordattempts%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

Also you won't find it in Web.config.

[According to Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12703192/2596334), if you want to set this property, you need to "implement it yourself".